# GIS SignInCredential does not contain field named "email", despite documentation guarantees

Tags: android, google-signin

The Google Identity Services documentation for Android [clearly states](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity#handle_sign_in_results):

> The result of a successful sign in always returns the users full name, email, and profile picture url.

And yet, the returned `SignInCredential` object does not expose `email`. It contains the name and profile picture URL, but not the `email`.

Is this

1. Documentation error;
2. SDK error;
3. My error?

And how do I obtain user email from Google Identity Services without going through People API then?

[image: SignInCredential without email]

Comment: id field is email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use :

```
signInCredential.getId();
```

you will get email .